# Publish and stop endpoint web service in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, webserver, endpoint

I am trying to start/stop an Endpoint web service in a separate thread from my main program with the click of a button. Starting works fine, i am able to access all my WebMethods without issue. The problem is, when i click the stop button to try and stop the web service endpoint, i get an exception and i don't know what it is. I am new to Java as well.

Thanks in advance.

Excetion thrown at 'ep.stop()':

```
WebService Running On: http://0.0.0.0:9898/

        Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.removeContext(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.stop(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.stop(Unknown Source)
            at com.simba.Server.startWebSrv(Server.java:27)
            at com.simba.Server.run(Server.java:13)
```

Server class:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Server extends Thread {

      public volatile boolean active = true;
      private Endpoint ep; 
      private String ip = "0.0.0.0";

      public void run(){
            ep = Endpoint.publish("http://" + ip + ":9898/",  new SWS());
            startWebSrv();
      }

      private void startWebSrv(){
          synchronized(this){
              try {
                  while (active) {
                      System.out.println("WebService Running On: http://" + ip + ":9898/");
                      wait();
                  }
              }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }finally{
                if(!active){
                    ep.stop();
                    System.out.println("WebService Stopped!");
                }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

How i am attempting to stop the service/thread from my main program:

```
MenuItem mntmToggleWebservice = new MenuItem(menu_4, SWT.NONE);
        mntmToggleWebservice.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                synchronized(srv){
                    srv.active = false;
                    srv.notifyAll();            
                }
            }
        });
        mntmToggleWebservice.setText("Toggle WebService");
```

Answer (score 8):

Problem solved!

Don't use `'0.0.0.0'`. For some reason, creating the service on '0.0.0.0' works (uses the machine's actual ip), but `Endpoint.stop()` doesn't not play well with it.

Instead I just used `'System.getEvn('COMPUTERNAME')'` and create the service with the machine name.

Comment: This should be the answer, I was using 0.0.0.0 and the error brought me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "input" to block the run of program

```
public class ServiceMain {

    private static void DoNothing() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String address = "http://127.0.0.1:7775/hb";  
        Endpoint ep = Endpoint.publish(address, new ServiceImp());
        Scanner scanIn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Web Service Release Successfully!"); 
        while(!scanIn.next().equals("stop")){
            DoNothing();
        }
        scanIn.close();
        ep.stop();
        System.out.println("Web Service Close Successfully!"); 

    }  
}
```