# JAX-WS Endpoint binding wildcard address prevents Endpoint to stop

Tags: jax-ws, endpoint

Using JSF2 on Tomcat7 (JDK7) to publish a JAX-WS Endpoint with a wildcard address:

```
Endpoint soapServer = Endpoint.publish( "http://0.0.0.0:8238/services",new MyHandler() );
```

the service self is working fine.
if i execute the stop method on the endpoint, the endpoint did not become stopped.

if i publish the endpoint with an static address like 192.168.1.1:8238/services
its possible to stop the endpoint.

why cant the endpoint being stopped if its running with a wildcard address ? (0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for using the (0.0.0.0) wildcard for the endpoint, as it won't sop, this issue should be fixed in newer versions, so you can update and if it is not fixed, you can use the solution propose here: [>Publish and stop endpoint web service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487762/publish-and-stop-endpoint-web-service-in-java)

For the bug fix on java.net: [Click Here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-941?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=306752#action_306752)